# CURL + Accept $_POST Data

Tags: php, curl

I'm doing the following with Curl:

```
 $authentication = $_POST['username'] . ':' . $_POST['passwd'];

 $params = array(
            'id' => '12',
            'field1' => 'field1text',
            'field2' => 'field2text',
            'field3' => 'field3text',
            'screenshots' => 'screenshots',
            'videoLinks' => 'videoLinks'
        );  

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.domain.com/scripts/curl/index_curl_general.php');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,$authentication);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,'http://www.domain.com.au');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain')); 
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
```

I'm finding I can see the username and password with this code - on the server side in index_curl_index.php

```
 print $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
 print $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
```

But I can seem to be able to see the `$params` data. I've tried the following:

```
 var_dump($_POST);
 print_r($_POST);
```

but it always shows as an empty array. How can I show this data? and is there a better way to pass this data?

Comment: You want to pass `$params` as `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` (and not `$temp`) ;)

Comment: could you put your `$temp` as well?

Comment: I've updated the question now... I have tried $params and I still get an empty array on the receiving end. any other ideas?

Comment: There might be cookies required (`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'cookies.txt');` `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookies.txt');`). What HTTP-code do you get back? (After the exec(): `$details = curl_getinfo($ch); echo $details['http_code'];`)

Comment: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookies.txt');
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   $details = curl_getinfo($ch); echo $details['http_code'];
   curl_close($ch);
   echo $details;                                           I added in the above and get 200200 back... does this mean anything to you?

Comment: why are you using this line: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain')); ? try to remove it for a test and check if you get what you need..

Comment: The HTTP code 200 means that the request was successful, which is good :) Where exactly do you print the output? What is `index_curl_index.php` you mentioned? The output (`print_r($_POST);`) must be done in the file you request (domain.com/scripts/curl/ **index_curl_general.php** )

Comment: And yes, as mishu mentioned, check what happens when you omit the `Content-Type`. (Also, I guess it should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `text/plain`)

Comment: And one more idea: Please check if the post-data is really being sent with the request. (You can easily do that with e.g. HTTP Live Headers (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/))

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$temp);
```

should be

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);
```

Whether there is a 'better' way to pass data around depends pretty much on what exactly you want to achieve. cURL is a very powerful library you can accomplish nearly everything with. Most of that you can also do with [file_get_contents()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) defining the HTTP-stuff in the [context](http://de.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php), so some people consider cURL as overkill. Personally, I prefer `file_get_contents` (for no specific reason, actually), but I don't know about any performance differences etc.